# How to send FCM Push Notifications with PHP

Tags: php, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm looking to send Push Notifications via FCM with firebase to both iOS and Android, but I'm getting a InvalidRegistration error.

Already tried different approaches and I always get the same error, so I don't know if the problem is with the code or some firebase configurations.
Here is what I have:

```
$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$notification = array('title' =>$message_title , 'body' => $message_body, 'message_type' => $message_type, 'content_id' => $content_id, 'data' => $content_url);
$arrayToSend = array('registration_ids' => $users_token_list,
'priority' => 'high', 'notification' => array('title' => 'Test', 'body' =>  $message ,'sound'=>'Default','image'=>'Notification Image' ),);
$headers = array('Authorization:key='.$allpush_google_api_key, Content-Type:application/json );
$json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "RESULT : ". $result;
echo $ch;
if ($result === FALSE || $result === 'JSON_PARSING_ERROR') {
  die('Oops! FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

The return for

```
echo "RESULT : ". $result;
```

is this:

```
{"multicast_id":7490342661176350728,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}
```

and

`echo $ch;`

Returns:

```
Resource id #1695
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The Error message hints that the tokens you are sending the notification to do either not exist or are not assigned to the Firebase project/application you‘re sending it from.

Comment: Oh so the token I'm using (from an iOS) is supposed to come from firebase. Ok I'm gonna have to change that and then I'll come back. Thank you.

Comment: @Paulo, where do you go? :)